# Multidimensional data type in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, generics, multidimensional-array, vector

I have a generic class, which is constructed from multi-dimensional data (i.e. n-dimensional `Arary`s or `Vector`s).
In this case, I would like the class to be instantiated by one type only (e.g. `Vector`), aside from its dimensionality (`Vector[Vector[T]]` but not `Vector[Array[T]]`).

Having this class signature:

```
class Foo[T](x: Vector[T], y: Bar[T])
```

how could I guarantee that T would be for example `Vector[T]` or `Vector[Vector[T]]` (or etc...) but NOT `Array[T]` or `Vector[Array[T]]`?

Comment: What's the difference between Vector[Array[Int]], which is two dimensional with different collection types and is not allowed, and Vector[Array[Int]], which is one dimensional with only one collection type (Vector), and the element type just *happens* to be Array[Int]? What happens if someone wants to give you a Vector[Vector[Int]], but they only want you to deal with the outer dimension and leave the inner one to them? As of now, what you want breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle: I can pass in a Vector[Any], but I can't give you a Vector[Seq[_]], even though it is a subtype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While generics are wiped out at compile time by type-erasure, you can rely on the "evidence" mechanism.

An evidence is a special typeclass whose goal is only to witness the relation between type A and type B.

```
A<:<B is a witness that A is a subclass of B
A=:=B is a witness that A is a B
A>:>B is a witness that A is a superclass of B
```

so you can write something like that

```
case class MyContainer[A,B](b:Vector[B])(implicit ev: B <:< Vector[A])
```

Inside your class, you can simply treat every element of vector b as a Vector A by applying the evidence to each item: i.e.

```
b flatMap {
   x => ev(x) map {_.toString}
}
```